# Android: Control the real size of the elements when printing using android print API

Tags: android, canvas, printing, size, draw

I want to fully control the real size of the elements that i place in the canvas when i print a page, but i'm struggling to achieve that. Although android documentation of the Android API says that each point of the canvas represents 1/72 of an inch:

https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html

"When using Canvas to draw on a PDF page, elements are specified in points, which is 1/72 of an inch. Make sure you use this unit of measure for specifying the size of elements on the page. For positioning of drawn elements, the coordinate system starts at 0,0 for the top left corner of the page."

With the tests that i've been performing i found this to be false or i'm interpreting something wrong, because the width and heigth of the canvas always comes in thousands of an inch, and i have a problem with this because let's imagine for the page format ISO_A4:

The measures in mm are 210mm x 297mm:
The measures in thousands of an inch that i get are 8270 x 11690 
So when i convert this to mm it results in:
(8270/1000)*25.4=210.058
(11690/1000)*25.4=296.926

And since i have to convert mm to thousand of an inch for a variety of things like, margins, line spacing, column spacing... this erros start to add up and in the end i have noticeable errors.

Does anybody know, another way of doing this?